# HTML / Javascript ReferenceError: Can't find variable

Tags: javascript

I've made extensive use of the search function and whilst there seem to be many instances of this problem, none are close enough for me to glean a solution to my variant of the problem.

I'm using vanilla Javascript to create a multiplication game. When the button is pressed either by the user pressing 'Enter' or clicking the button the console shows me this error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: checkAnswer

Here is the code:

```
var user_answer;
  for(var x in questions){
    document.getElementById("bronze").innerHTML = '<p>' + questions[x] + '</p>';
    document.getElementById("bronze").innerHTML += '<p><input type="number" id="user_input"></p>';
    document.getElementById("bronze").innerHTML += '<p><button type="button" id="submit_button" onclick="checkAnswer()">Enter</button></p>';
    var user_input = document.getElementById("user_input");
    user_input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){
      if(event.keyCode == 13){
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("submit_button").click();
      }
    });
    function checkAnswer(){
      user_answer = document.getElementById("user_input").value;
      if(user_answer == answers[x]){
        alert('Correct!');
      } else {
        alert('Wrong!');
      }
    }
  }
```

Edit to say that questions and answers are arrays each containing the questions and corresponding answers in the same position. So questions will be like [1x2,2x2,...] and answers [2,4,...]

Comment: Your code is broken to begin with - IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document, but you are creating the same ones multiple times in your loop.

Comment: `for...in` is for objects and not arrays.

Comment: @Andreas: Looks like OP wants to have access to `x`.

Comment: You've placed your `checkAnswer` function _inside_ your for/loop. Move it outside, and call it with `checkAnswer(x)`.

Comment: A function called from an inline event handler needs to be global, but `checkAnswer` isn't. You don't need a separate function for every input but if you want to do it this way then use the DOM API to create the elements and bind the event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for such fast replies. You were all correct so I couldn't pick one answer but here's what I did:

1. Moved the checkAnswer function outside the for loop.
2. Made 'answers' and 'x' global variables by declaring them outside the function(s).